# Convergence warnings in glmer from lme4 package + weird standard errors of estimated fixed coefficients

Tags: r, glm, lme4, mixed-models

I am working on a generalized linear mixed model with binomial link.
My dependent variable is a score varying from 0 to 12 for each of 107 subjects (63 subjects are control and 44 subjects have the disease A). The test leading to the score is repeated 2 times with different versions.
I want to test wether there is a group difference (control VS disease A), wether there is a version difference and the interaction between group and version.

I use `glmer` from `lme4` :

```
glmer(cbind(score, 12-score) ~ gender + age + group + version + group:version  + (1|id), data = data, family="binomial")



Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: cbind(score, 12-score) ~ gender + age + group + version + group:version + (1 | id)
   Data: data
     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   764.7    788.2   -375.4    750.7      206 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-6.1421 -0.6240  0.3693  0.7269  3.4653 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id     (Intercept) 0.3852   0.6207  
Number of obs: 213, groups:  id, 107

Fixed effects:
                              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                  3.4707862  0.0017104  2029.2   <2e-16 ***
genderH                      0.3402744  0.0017093   199.1   <2e-16 ***
age                         -0.0152378  0.0009988   -15.3   <2e-16 ***
groupCTRL                    0.9554189  0.0017101   558.7   <2e-16 ***
versionunknown              -2.0853952  0.0017089 -1220.3   <2e-16 ***
groupCTRL:versionunknown     0.1156636  0.0017092    67.7   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) SexeH  age    gropNC fmlrtn
SexeH        0.000                            
age         -0.016 -0.006                     
groupeNC     0.001  0.000 -0.008              
familrtncnn  0.000  0.000 -0.013  0.000       
grpNC:fmlrt  0.000  0.000 -0.007  0.000  0.000
convergence code: 0
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0420639 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?
```

I follow the different steps in this link : https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/33653_57fc7b8e5d484c909b615d8633c01d51.html to handle the convergence failure.
None of these steps allow to take care of this issue.

Moreover, the standard errors of estimated fixed coefficients are almost the same except for age coefficients. So I can see there is a real trouble here.

Is someone could help me?

Comment: Did you rescale the variables, increase iterations etc. You could also try simplifying the fixed effects by removing the interaction. One point is whether a mixed effects model is actually needed as you have 213 observations but 107 groups: so not a lot of info to estimate the between errors : this can cause problems in estimating : but that's probably more a question for http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions . ps maybe some more things to try at `?convergence`

Comment: Yes I already  rescale the variables, increase iterations, restart from previous fit and try lots of different optimizers. In my analysis I am interested in the significance of the interaction so I can't remove. And I first posted my question on stats.stackexchange but I have been reoriented here. Thanks for answering.

Comment: I understand that you have a hypothesis on the interaction, but convergence problems are not necessarily due to computational or algorithmic defects but by fitting a model too complex to be supported by the data. Steps I would take; I would experiment by fitting it without the interaction - does it converge? Then try using `update` to add the interaction: (this sometimes helps,for whatever reason). Id also fitting a standard glm (without random intercept and without interaction) and compare to the mixed-effects model. Not ideal, but sometimes the solution is to reduce the models complexity.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I finally used a standard GLM even if it does not into account for the correlations among observations. Graph fitted vs residuals was ok.